# Reversing a string recursively

Tags: java, string, recursion, user-input

Simple program that uses recursion to reverse a string. The only problem is that I get an error when I run the program.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class reverseString {

     public static String reverseTheString(String s){
         if (s.length() == 0)
            return s;
        return reverseTheString(s.substring(1) + s.charAt(0));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter a string to be reversed.");
        String s = keyboard.nextLine();
        reverseTheString(s);

    }
}
```

Comment: change `s.length() == 0` to `s.length() == 1`

Answer (score 1):

It will fail on the recursive call when the string's length == 1, since in that case you'll still be dereferencing at index 0 and 1 (out of bounds).

Reverse makes sense for strings length >= 2.  Change your ground check to that.